# How to achieve a blend of Top Down 2D and Isometric maps/art like in Sea of Stars?

Tags: 2d, isometric, top-down

I recently started playing Sea of Stars and what amazed me was the seamless blend of Isometric and Top Down 2D. Sometimes even in the same map. It's what I have in mind for the game I'm currently planning, but I'm racking my brain at how to achieve similar  things.

Isometric
[image: Isometric]

Top Down
[image: Top Down]

At first I assumed it's a top down 2d tile map with isometric art, but then there's the added elevation that makes me completely uncertain how they achieved such things.

[image: Elevation]

Comment: Getting both perspectives to align to one shared tile grid could be challenging, but one could also just not have a tile grid. I don't see much evidence of full tile repeats in these images — there are a lot of large structures that would need to span many tiles. So they may have just done away with tiles entirely and built the game out of textured polygons and layered sprites — at which point you're free to mix angles any way you like since there's no rigid grid they have to conform to. They could even have built their environments in 3D, making it easier to get correct light shapes.

Comment: @DMGregory That's what I was thinking of as well. And I'm contemplating going that route since sticking to a strict tilemap is feeling quite restrictive from what I've attempted so far. Tilemaps should make life easier but I'm spending most of the time trying to make various assets from different sources fit into pixel perfect grids.